# adding css in fresh.css nothing change is made

Tags: 7

I'm using sub theme zenophile and created sub theme and now in my own sub theme I added some css rules in fresh.css but it's changing nothing.

I did clean refresh, but nothing happening...

Comment: How to add that css files in that subtheme ?

Comment: I created from zenophile sub theme which creates my own defined subtheme and now I tried in that .... but actually how to add css really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your theme to pickup your css file.. You can do that using .info file of theme using below code..

```
stylesheets[all][] = fresh.css
```

Clear Drupal Cache to see changes...

For more information refer [Writing theme.info files](https://drupal.org/node/171205)...

Comment: oh! stylesheets[all][] = css/fresh.css worked thanks....I'll accept in few mins.